# Migrate an existing application from Flex to AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, apache-flex

I have to migrate an application (project with alot of front and back work ) developped with flex to angular js.

I want to know how can I achieve that?

Should I create a front application from scratch ? steps ? ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am also going to work in similar application looks like need to scratch in Angular.